# org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path is not list all s3 files on unix EC2

Tags: hadoop, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am using Flink and read / write parquet file on s3 bucket.

My Window code is list all parquet file under business folder and getting list of files.

```
            Path file = new Path("C:\\tmp\\business");
            List<String> fileList= listFileInDir(file.toString());
```

when moving same code on unix box its working fine for single file (fullpath) however not reading list all parquet file under s3 folder  and getting null in lists of files( tried all s3 , s3a and s3n)

```
            Path file = new Path("s3n://java-filink-vkhan/parquet");
            List<String> fileList= listFileInDir(file.toString());
```

Method is reading Path as String

```
        public List<String> listFileInDir(String path) {

            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

            File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
            // If this pathname does not denote a directory, then listFiles() returns null.
         if(null != files) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    results.add(file.getName());
                }
            }
         }
            return results;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 is specifically bad(slow) with listing files in a directory.  This has to do with how S3 implements its file directories.  If you need speed, you should actually do your own "accounting" of [what files you have written] and [where you wrote them] in a database.  This is also what Amazon themselves suggested to fix [HDFS lookups for hive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.PerformanceTuning.html). (They suggest using dynamoDB, it was used to help provide consistency but also solved issues with slow lookups.)